# Getting data in textbox

Tags: c#, sql, textbox

I want to do " When I write "Item Code" on textbox and click search, It will search & found that item in sql database which has that item code . And Bring it name to textbox2(ITEM NAME). How can I do it ? I can bring it on colomn/raw but Idk how can I bring that item name on textbox2

[image]

I can search data on database and bring it to dataGridview . With this code

```
if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "") errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Fiil in the blanks");
else errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "");

conn.Open();
string regs = "SELECT * from stackTable where itemCodu=@Cod";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(regs, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", textBox1.Text);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gridView.DataSource = dt;
conn.Close();
```

---operation sequence ( Which I want to do :D )

1. Search on Database
2. If found, bring data on Textbox2
3. If didn't find, Error provider, message textbox

Comment: You're a little unclear, are you not wanting to use the dataGridView? You could bind the textbox to the data and for the error, check to see if the dt has a rows.count > 0

Comment: Thanks for your comment :)
Datagridview is just for example , I want to do database to textbox , . 
 ""check to see if the dt has a rows.count > 0"" this part is okay but Idk , how can I do textbox.Text("that info from database" ) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a datatable, all you should have to do is to check the count after the fill with a simple if statement:

```
if(dt.rows.count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Found!!");
}
else
{  
    textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "the column you want to use for textbox2");
}
```

You should also be using `using` statements so that all the objects are disposed of properly.

here's an example of how I would write what you have:

```
textbox2.DataBinding.Clear(); //clear the databinding so it can be added for the new data found.

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string here")
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from stackTable where itemCodu=@Cod")
{
     da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cod", sqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text; //see comment below for this change
     da.fill(dt);
     if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
     {
         //display not found message
     }
     else
     {
         //bind to textbox (described above)
     }
 }
```

Also note, instead of allowing the parameter to be implicitly typed, it is often better to specify the type of data the parameter should receive. This can be done by using Add instead of AddWithValue

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod", SqlType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
```

The last thing to note with your code is that you can use the sqlDataAdapter without the SqlCommand.

One other thing I thought I should add:

If you know you will only ever receive 1 or 0 rows from the search, and you're not interested in binding the data, you could simply just set the textbox's `.Text` to the column of the row in the datatable.

For example, if you wanted to display a column in your table named Item you could simply use

```
textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Item"].ToString();
```

Comment: I didnt understand a lot of parts but you spent your time and You deserved green tick. Thanks my friend . I will try to read it again tomorrow morning.